# gui zero not finding image

Tags: python-3.x, file-not-found, guizero

im working on a program that will randomly choose and display 5 tarot cards. sadly i keep getting this error (*** GUIZERO ERROR ***
Image import error - '[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '6.png''
Check the file path and image type is GIF/Animated GIF/BMP/ICO/PNG/JPG/TIF). all of the images are in the exact same directory as the script file im running so i have no clue what to do. using the full path is not an option as i want this project to beable to work in a differnt location. if you guys could give me some pointers that would be great!

my code:

```
`from random import*
from guizero import App, Picture, PushButton
#### lists and other variables ####
cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
drawn_cards = []
card1 = ()
card2 = ()
card3 = ()
card4 = ()
card5 = ()
#### functions ####

def display_cards():
    pic1 = Picture(app, image =(card1+".png"),align="top")
    pic2 = Picture(app, image =(card2+".png"),align="left")
    pic3 = Picture(app, image =(card3+".png"),align="left")
    pic4 = Picture(app, image =(card4+".png"),align="left")
    pic5 = Picture(app, image =(card5+".png"),align="bottom")

def card_drawer():
    global cards
    global drawn_cards
    global card1
    global card2
    global card3
    global card4
    global card5
    loops = 0
    while loops < 5:
        drawn = (choice(cards))
        drawn_cards.append(drawn)
        cards.remove (drawn)
        loops = loops + 1
    card1 = (drawn_cards[0])
    card2 = (drawn_cards[1])
    card3 = (drawn_cards[2])
    card4 = (drawn_cards[3])
    card5 = (drawn_cards[4])
    card1 = str(card1)
    card2 = str(card2)
    card3 = str(card3)
    card4 = str(card4)
    card5 = str(card5)
    display_cards()

    
#### gui stuff ####
app = App()
reading = PushButton(app, text = "draw cards",align="bottom", command = card_drawer)`
```

Comment: Is `6.png` in your current working directory? Your file paths need to either be absolute or relative to the current working directory.

Comment: @PranavHosangad I think so. is the working directory the directory that the script file is in? im new to programming and not up to all the jargon

Comment: @PranavHosangadi just checked the jargon. do i need to specify the working directory when giving the program the path to the image or can i just say the path is the image name.file extension?

Comment: The working directory is the directory that you executed this python script in. When you refer to a file as `name.ext` (or any relative path), it is assumed to be relative to this working directory. You can check this with `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi so i dont need to specify the working directory in the path if the file i want to get is in the working directory? so instead of saying `working_directory/file_name.ext` i can say `file_name.ext`?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `random` module in python is not truly random as it is based on the Mersenne Twister as its core generator which is deterministic. For instance, if you set a seeding value using `random.seed()`, the sequence will be the same. Simply using `choice()` alone isn't enough to represent the 'randomness' required for a Tarot-esque sample.

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out, windows thinks that files with names such as 1.png are named as intergers and not strings, i switched numbering of the files to roman numerals and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).